# Drag a mesh over another and limit it within the sides three.js

Tags: 3d, three.js, drag-and-drop, intersection

I have to create a house like structure where user will be able to add windows on wall. The approach I am thinking is to first create a separate mesh for window which user can drag over the selected wall of the house mesh, and drops where they feel it suitable, but within the same wall or same side of the house mesh. After that I will create the whole scene again but draw the window in the wall of the house mesh instead of creating a separate window mesh.

Following is what it will look like when a window mesh is seen over a wall-
[image: window over wall]

I am able to drag the window over wall using the DragControls.

```
dragControls = new THREE.DragControls( objects, camera, renderer.domElement );
```

but don't know how to limit the dragging so that window cannot go outside of the wall.

Its a working sample where I have created building mesh and window mesh which can be dragged - [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5exceptions/0z3z6y7w/34/).

Comment: Take a look at [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/bkwvg3xL/). How to move/drag an object over the other one.

Comment: @prisoner849 - Thanks a lot. I have updated my code sample, please have a look - https://jsfiddle.net/5exceptions/0z3z6y7w/44/. Now the window mesh gets visible over wall but its size changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without `THREE.DragControls()`. Just check, if the ray of your raycaster is intersecting the wall/building and, if it is, set window's position at the point of intersection.

There's a rough solution, which can be just the starting point for your creativity:

```js
var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

var building = new THREE.Mesh(...); // wall/building
var _window = new THREE.Mesh(...);  // window

var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
var intersects;
var normalMatrix = new THREE.Matrix3();
var worldNormal = new THREE.Vector3();
var lookAtVector = new THREE.Vector3();
var dragging = false;

window.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove, false);
window.addEventListener("mousedown", onMouseDown, false);
window.addEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp, false);

function onMouseDown(event) {
    if (intersects.length > 0) {
        controls.enableRotate = false;
        dragging = true;
    }
}

function onMouseUp(event) {
    controls.enableRotate = true;
    dragging = false;
}

function onMouseMove(event) {
    mouse.set((event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1, -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1);
    raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
    intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects([building]);

    if (intersects.length == 0 || !dragging) return;

    normalMatrix.getNormalMatrix(intersects[0].object.matrixWorld);
    worldNormal.copy(intersects[0].face.normal).applyMatrix3(normalMatrix).normalize();
    _window.position.copy(intersects[0].point);
    _window.lookAt(lookAtVector.copy(intersects[0].point).add(worldNormal));
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/Lacsa4y4/) example r87

Comment: Thanks, let me try it.

Comment: Please have a look at the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/5exceptions/0z3z6y7w/52/.

Comment: Don't forget to calculate face normals for your custom geometry. Using of a Lambert material with a directional light source will show you mistakes you've made in order of vertices in some faces [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/0z3z6y7w/55/). In this fiddle, take a look at the coordinates of vertices for the second object.

Comment: Please visit the stackoverflow chat room : https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155735/dragovermesh. I need some suggestions and help.

Answer (score 0):

While the existing answer is correct, this can also achieved by making slight modification to the source code of the drag controls.

Adding the following inside the pointerMove event

```js
if (targetMesh) { // add this if condition
  const intersection = _raycaster.intersectObjects(targetMesh);

  if (intersection.length > 0) {
    const intersect = intersection[0];
    _selected.position.copy(intersect.point);
  }
}else if ( _raycaster.ray.intersectPlane( _plane, _intersection ) ) {

    const pos = _intersection.sub( _offset ).applyMatrix4( _inverseMatrix )

    _selected.position.copy(pos);

}
```

so now your `drag-controls.js` code should look like this:

```js
import {
    EventDispatcher,
    Matrix4,
    Plane,
    Raycaster,
    Vector2,
    Vector3,
    Camera,
    Mesh
} from 'three';

const _plane = new Plane();
const _raycaster = new Raycaster();

const _pointer = new Vector2();
const _offset = new Vector3();
const _intersection = new Vector3();
const _worldPosition = new Vector3();
const _inverseMatrix = new Matrix4();

class DragControls extends EventDispatcher {

    /**
     * 
     * @param {Mesh[]} _objects 
     * @param {Camera} _camera 
     * @param {HTMLElement} _domElement 
     * @param {Mesh[]} targetMesh 
     */

    constructor( _objects, _camera, _domElement, targetMesh ) {

        super();

        _domElement.style.touchAction = 'none'; // disable touch scroll

        let _selected = null, _hovered = null;

        const _intersections = [];

        this.targetMesh = targetMesh

        const scope = this;

        function activate() {

            _domElement.addEventListener( 'pointermove', onPointerMove );
            _domElement.addEventListener( 'pointerdown', onPointerDown );
            _domElement.addEventListener( 'pointerup', onPointerCancel );
            _domElement.addEventListener( 'pointerleave', onPointerCancel );

        }

        function deactivate() {

            _domElement.removeEventListener( 'pointermove', onPointerMove );
            _domElement.removeEventListener( 'pointerdown', onPointerDown );
            _domElement.removeEventListener( 'pointerup', onPointerCancel );
            _domElement.removeEventListener( 'pointerleave', onPointerCancel );

            _domElement.style.cursor = '';

        }

        function dispose() {

            deactivate();

        }

        function getObjects() {

            return _objects;

        }

        function getRaycaster() {

            return _raycaster;

        }

        function onPointerMove( event ){

            if ( scope.enabled === false ) return;

            updatePointer( event );

            _raycaster.setFromCamera( _pointer, _camera );

            if ( _selected ) {


                if (scope.targetMesh){

                    const intersection = _raycaster.intersectObjects(scope.targetMesh)

                    if (intersection.length > 0){
                        const intersect = intersection[0]
                        _selected.position.copy(intersect.point)
                    }
                }

                else if ( _raycaster.ray.intersectPlane( _plane, _intersection ) ) {

                    const pos = _intersection.sub( _offset ).applyMatrix4( _inverseMatrix )

                    _selected.position.copy(pos);

                }

                scope.dispatchEvent( { type: 'drag', object: _selected } );

                return;

            }

            // hover support

            if ( event.pointerType === 'mouse' || event.pointerType === 'pen' ) {

                _intersections.length = 0;

                _raycaster.setFromCamera( _pointer, _camera );
                _raycaster.intersectObjects( _objects, true, _intersections );

                if ( _intersections.length > 0 ) {

                    const object = _intersections[ 0 ].object;

                    _plane.setFromNormalAndCoplanarPoint( _camera.getWorldDirection( _plane.normal ), _worldPosition.setFromMatrixPosition( object.matrixWorld ) );

                    if ( _hovered !== object && _hovered !== null ) {

                        scope.dispatchEvent( { type: 'hoveroff', object: _hovered } );

                        _domElement.style.cursor = 'auto';
                        _hovered = null;

                    }

                    if ( _hovered !== object ) {

                        scope.dispatchEvent( { type: 'hoveron', object: object } );

                        _domElement.style.cursor = 'pointer';
                        _hovered = object;

                    }

                } else {

                    if ( _hovered !== null ) {

                        scope.dispatchEvent( { type: 'hoveroff', object: _hovered } );

                        _domElement.style.cursor = 'auto';
                        _hovered = null;

                    }

                }

            }

        }

        function onPointerDown( event ) {

            if ( scope.enabled === false ) return;

            updatePointer( event );

            _intersections.length = 0;

            _raycaster.setFromCamera( _pointer, _camera );
            _raycaster.intersectObjects( _objects, true, _intersections );

            if ( _intersections.length > 0 ) {

                _selected = ( scope.transformGroup === true ) ? _objects[ 0 ] : _intersections[ 0 ].object;

                _plane.setFromNormalAndCoplanarPoint( _camera.getWorldDirection( _plane.normal ), _worldPosition.setFromMatrixPosition( _selected.matrixWorld ) );

                if ( _raycaster.ray.intersectPlane( _plane, _intersection ) ) {

                    _inverseMatrix.copy( _selected.parent.matrixWorld ).invert();
                    _offset.copy( _intersection ).sub( _worldPosition.setFromMatrixPosition( _selected.matrixWorld ) );

                }

                _domElement.style.cursor = 'move';

                scope.dispatchEvent( { type: 'dragstart', object: _selected } );

            }


        }

        function onPointerCancel() {

            if ( scope.enabled === false ) return;

            if ( _selected ) {

                scope.dispatchEvent( { type: 'dragend', object: _selected } );

                _selected = null;

            }

            _domElement.style.cursor = _hovered ? 'pointer' : 'auto';

        }

        function updatePointer( event ) {

            const rect = _domElement.getBoundingClientRect();

            _pointer.x = ( event.clientX - rect.left ) / rect.width * 2 - 1;
            _pointer.y = - ( event.clientY - rect.top ) / rect.height * 2 + 1;

        }

        activate();

        // API

        this.enabled = true;
        this.transformGroup = false;

        this.activate = activate;
        this.deactivate = deactivate;
        this.dispose = dispose;
        this.getObjects = getObjects;
        this.getRaycaster = getRaycaster;

    }

}

export { DragControls };
```

Now you can pass your target mesh to the constructor and use it normally.

example [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/threejs-draggable-example-vzcn4p?file=/src/App.js) (zoom out and start dragging the sphere on the plane)